# Selenium c#: reuse existing browser session, instead of opening new windows?

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

How can i run all test methods in single browser session instead of opening and closing browser for each test method using selenium c#.
E.g.

```
    [TestInitialize]
    public void Startup()
    {

        driver = new FirefoxDriver();

        driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://testurl:2022");
        driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//a[contains(@id, 'tabDrugDimention')]")).Click();
        System.Console.WriteLine("Dimension page loaded");
        driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//a[contains(text(), 'Testcontent')]")).Click();
        System.Console.WriteLine("Drug Item clicked");
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void DrugAnalysisclick()
    {
        ...        
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void DrugAnalysisclick()
    {
        ...
    }

    [TestCleanup]
    public void TearDown()
    {
        driver.Quit();
    }
```

For all test method, new browser window is opening and getting closed for each test method.

Can anyone help, how to run all test method in single browser?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You just have to reuse the same driver for every test instead of calling `driver.Quit()` after each test. As pointed out in the comments you have to be careful with this as you break up the test isolation by reusing the driver.

Comment: plus one - and to further add to that; make sure you (i.e. the OP) understands the implications of not having each driver instance self contained for each test. this is not something I would recommend as the goal is to test each element in isolation and then conduct a *super test* that includes the entire workflow